# How to detect end of partition with kafka-python?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-python, confluent-kafka-python

I want to try the *kafka-python* package instead of the Confluent Kafka python binding because I want a pure Python package and only *kafka-python* does that. However, I am unable to work out how to implement a particular behaviour that I depend on in Confluent Kafka.

In the Confluent Kafka python binding it is possible to configure the consumer to return an error message when the end of a partition has been reached. I use this to detect when there are no more messages to process, at least for a while.  However, I cannot work out the *right* way to do the same thing with *kafka-python*.

I *could* request the end offset from the *KakfaConsumer* before I start processing messages but this introduces a race condition; the end offset could move after I query it and while I'm processing messages. Alternatively, I *could* request end offsets after processing every message but I'm worried that there may be a performance penalty associated with this approach.

So, while I have a number of ideas about what I *could* do, I don't know what I *should* do.

Any clues as to the accepted method would be welcome.